# Docker Compose apps automatically bind to same port but compose doesn't start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two copies of the same application that I want to deploy in a cluster and I'm using `docker-compose` for now. This application listens to port 8000 and if the port is busy it increments the port number until it finds a free port (8001, 8002 etc). These ports are used for the apps to communicate with each other, i.e. *app1* will listen to 8000 and talk to *app2* in 8001.

Since I'm deploying these using `docker-compose`, each container gets their own IP address. This means that **both apps** will bind to port 8000 (since it's not busy from their perspective). Knowing this, I'm trying to map those `ports` in the docker-compose.yml file as follows

```
version: "3.9"
  services:
    app1:
      container_name: app1
      image: app:latest
      ports:
        - 8000:8000
    app2:
      container_name: app2
      image: app:latest
      ports:
        - 8000:8001
```

However, when I try to `docker-compose up` this thing it fails with the following error

> bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated

i.e. it can't bind the same *container (internal)* port even though they are from different containers and are mapped to different *host* ports. Both `app1` and `app2` will choose port 8000 because from their perspective is free but I'm unable to map it externally. How can I solve this?

My preference would be for each `app` to bind to a different port i.e. the whole compose setup should share the same ports even though containers have different IP adresses.

NOTE: Changing the port selection code is not an option, this is a third party library and frankly it's a regular pattern to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have swapped the ports around. The first port is the *host* port and the second port is the internal *container* port.

Try

```
version: "3.9"
  services:
    app1:
      container_name: app1
      image: app:latest
      ports:
        - 8000:8000
    app2:
      container_name: app2
      image: app:latest
      ports:
        - 8001:8000
```

That will map the containers to host ports 8000 and 8001.

Comment: I'm so mad right now I'm about to delete this question. I'm only keeping it so you get the points